# How to avoid upright-shape subscripts clashing with the slanted-shape variables in helvet?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subscripts, helvetica, sansmathfonts

When using sans-serif math, I have found that upright-shape subscripts can clash with the slanted-shape variables they are attached to, as shown in particular with `p_{in}`, `p_t` and `Q_{in}`:

[image]
[image]

It is important that the `p` remains in slanted shape and the subscript is in upright shape due to a typographic convention I must adhere to. I would also like the equations to match the helvetica style font in the body of the document, however I am willing to change this if there is no way to fix this problem.

The lines I use to change the document font are:

```
\usepackage[scaled=1.0]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\linespread{1.6}
```

I also use `amsmath`.

I have tried various different ways to style the equation font, such as:

```
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}  
%\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
```

I used both `\text` and `\mathrm` on the subscript in each case and got the same problems of clashing text. I am using pdfLatex to prduce the pdf file with texmaker.

Any help to fix this or letting me know there is no way around this would be really appreciated. 
thanks

Oh, and here is the equation I am using:

```
\begin{equation}  
\alpha_t V_{t} \frac{\partial p_t}{\partial t} = \frac{2 \uppi K R L}{h} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} ( p_{in} + p_{out}) - p_{t} \bigg) - M V_{t}   
\label{eq:metabolism balance}   
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are `K`, `R`, and `L` three separate variables? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, and yes they are

Comment: In that case, it may be worth writing `K\cdot R\cdot L`. Otherwise, readers might get confused by the different kerns inserted between `K` and `R` and between `R` and `L`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to emphasize that the issue is not so much roman (serif) versus sans-serif but upright (serif or sans-serif) versus slanted (serif or sans-serif. The reason why this distinction matters -- at least in the TeX/Computer Modern (CM) world -- is because CM features both upright and slanted roman font shapes as well as slanted and upright (yes, there is such a thing) italic font shapes. Your posting seemed to equate roman and upright and italic and slanted; this might needless cause confusion. You're obviously free to revert if you don't agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sans-serif font designed for math.  As of May 2020, the only one in OpenType is Fira Math.  If you need to use legacy 8-bit fonts in PDFTeX, you can combine it with `newtxsf`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
  \usepackage[upint,slantedGreek]{newtxsf}
\else
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \setmainfont{Fira Sans}[Scale = 1.0]
  \setsansfont{Fira Sans}
  \setmathfont{Fira Math}
\fi

\newcommand\upt{\mathrm{t}}
\newcommand\subin{\mathop{\mathrm{in}}}
\newcommand\subout{\mathop{\mathrm{out}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}  
\alpha_{\upt} V_{\upt} \frac{\partial p_\upt}{\partial t} = \frac{2 \uppi K R L}{h} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} ( p_{\subin} + p_{\subout}) - p_{\upt} \bigg) - M V_{\upt}   
\label{eq:metabolism balance}   
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Math sample]

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> I would also like the equations to match the helvetica style font in the body of the document, however I am willing to change this if there is no way to fix this problem.

I'm not aware of high-quality *Helvetica* math font implementations. You may want to look into using the `arev` font package. For sure, it doesn't generate the (near-)collisions between slanted-mode variables and upright-mode subscript terms.

[image]

Incidentally, if the subscript `t` in `\partial p_t` should be rendered in upright mode, then so should the `t` in `\partial t`, right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev} % 2 components: 'arevtext' and 'arevmath' 
\begin{document}
\[ 
\alpha_{\mathrm{t}} V_{\mathrm{t}} 
\frac{\partial p_{\mathrm{t}}}{\partial\mathrm{t}} 
= \frac{2 \pi K\,R\,L}{h} 
\Bigl( \tfrac{1}{2} ( p_{\mathrm{in}} + p_{\mathrm{out}}) 
- p_{\mathrm{t}} \Bigr) - M\,V_{\mathrm{t}}    
\]

\begin{multline*}
V_{\mathrm{b}}\frac{1}{2}\biggl(
\frac{\partial S_{\mathrm{in}}}{\partial\mathrm{t}}+
\frac{\partial S_{\mathrm{out}}}{\partial\mathrm{t}}
\biggr)
+\tfrac{1}{2}(
Q_{\mathrm{in}}+Q_{\mathrm{out}})(
S_{\mathrm{in}}+S_{\mathrm{out}})\\
=-\frac{2\pi K\,R\,L}{hc_{\mathrm{Hb}}H}
\Bigl( \tfrac{1}{2} ( p_{\mathrm{in}} + p_{\mathrm{out}}) 
- p_{\mathrm{t}} \Bigr)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mico. In this case, the t attached to p denotes tissue while t as a parameter denotes time, so t should remain italic. It's good to know helvet has these issues, was pulling my hair out trying to work around it. This document is for a masters thesis for which they specific Arial font, and arev seems much squatter. Is arev the closest font to Arial with high-quality math font implementations? Or alternatively, I could use helvet for the text and arev just for math. From your experience, how would you proceed?